# Issue in si delayer component of spring integration. Once the server is down the recovery of delayer does not happen

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, oracle12c

We have used delayer backed by message store in our solution and put the delay of 15 min for the message to flow if some spel expression condition is true.
But if the application server is restarted in middle then delayer becomes a curse for the solution and all the messages are not being recovered from delayer and it becomes a dangling situation. 
Please suggest.
code :

```
<int:delayer id="mydelayer" input-channel="DelayerOutputChannel"
        output-channel="letChannel" default-delay="1000"
        expression="payload.comm.code == 'ABC' ? #{eodConfigMap['ABC']} :( payload.comm.code == 'DEF' ? #{eodConfigMap['DEF']} : (payload.commRequest.code == 'GHI' ? #{eodConfigMap['GHI']} : #{eodConfigMap['FGH']}))"
        message-store="siMessageStore"   />

<util:map id="eodConfigMap" key-type="java.lang.String"
        value-type="java.lang.String" scope="singleton" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="FDG" value="1000"/>
        <entry key="ABC" value="1000"/>
        <entry key="DEF" value="1000"/>
        <entry key="GHI" value="1000"/>
    </util:map>

        <int-jdbc:message-store id="siMessageStore" data-source="jndiDataSource" region="DEF_DELAY"
     table-prefix="MY_TABLE_SIDELAY"/>
```

Regards
Ram

Comment: Would you mind to find some time to chat? I don't see any problem with your config, so I need to ask you some question and investigation with your application. The `rescheduling` feature is there already for a while. Really isn't clear what the problem you have... Would be better if you come up with something what I can use locally to reproduce. The Spring Integration version first of all?

Comment: Artem, SI version is 4.1.2.RELEASE. Let me tell you how you can reproduce this issue. Run a web application having a delayer backed by message store with delay of 15 min and then when you post your message and then stop the web server in the middle just that 15 min must not have passed so that when you start your web server see if that message is processed again and check whether rescheduling mechanism works. Sure we can chat let me know your id so that I can chat with you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I need some enough short test-case to play from the Framework perspective and even debug. I think you mean something like this for ID: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan